# What does this means in this context ? 気組みを外してみたものの……どう対応したものだろうな (MC's thought after a girl asked him to withdraw from a proposal and leave)

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**Context: MC had accepted a proposal from a clan leader, that he'll become her husband. After that the clan leader had to leave, but she had ordered another girl who's also her wife (yuri-nice ^^) to come and serve a meal for MC.**

**This girl don't want MC to become the "new" husband of her husband, so while MC is eating she asked him to withdraw his promise and leave the country.**

**Hope someone can explain to me the correct meaning of his thought here.**

**（気組みを外してみたものの……どう対応したものだろうなー……） (my guess : "Though I tried to remove her
hostile attitude... How should I respond to her ..." but I'm not sure)**

Girl「……あなたに久遠の夫が務まるとは思えませんが」

ストレートだなぁ。敵意を隠そうともしないし。こういうタイプ、苦手なんだよなぁ……。

Girl「あなたにあの子の何が分かるのです？……気楽な気持ちで受けたのならば、すぐに撤回し、この国から出て行ってくれませんか」

MC「……………………（モグモグ）」

Girl「ちょっと、あなた。私の話、聞いているの？」

MC「あの」

Girl「何でしょう？出て行くつもりになりましたか？」

MC「ご飯、おかわりもらって良いですか？」

Girl「え！？あ、​ ……どうぞ」

差し出したお椀を両手で受け取り、お櫃からご飯をよそってくれる、帰蝶と名乗った少女。

MC（お椀の受け取り方といい、ご飯のよそい方といい、丁寧にやってくれるなー……）

ということは、だ。俺に出て行け、と言うのは、感情的なところからの発言じゃなくて、もっと理性的な判断ってことだろう。

**MC（気組みを外してみたものの……どう対応したものだろうなー……）**

織田久遠の妻と名乗ったからには、この女の子も、織田家中で偉い立場の人だろう。

その人が理性的な判断から、俺に約束を反故にし、この国から去れ、というなら、それは一考しなくちゃならないだろう。

Answer (score 1):

気組みを外す is not a common set phrase, but 気組み is *readiness* or *alertness* rather than *hostile attitude*. From the context, I think this 気組み refers to MC's own attitude, and the sentence means that MC let down his guard and became more relaxed.

Comment: there's no subject in the sentence , so i thought MC are talking about the girl , not himself ? Also i don't see MC are showing "readiness" or "alertness" or "let his guard down" to the girl ? (because he's eating)

Comment: @casualreader Hmm, on second thought, you might be right if MC is a smart person and said おかわりもらって良いですか on purpose to calm her down. 気組みを外す is not something I have seen before, so I can only guess as well.